# Mapping of source code to object file

Tags: c, objdump

I wanted to how this mapping done between source file and the object file

```
void main()
{
     printf("Hello world !!\n");
}
```

With the object file:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:

   0:   55                      push   %ebp

   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp

   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp

   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp

   9:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax

   e:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)

  11:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   12 <main+0x12>

  16:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax

  1b:   c9                      leave  

  1c:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `--source --line-numbers` options?

Comment: Related: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) / https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 2):

```
objdump -d ./a.out --source --line-numbers
```

Works like a charm !

```
000000000040052c <main>:
main():
/home/stdcall/temp/test.c:2
void main()
{
  40052c:   55                      push   %rbp
  40052d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
/home/stdcall/temp/test.c:3
     printf("Hello world !!\n");
  400530:   bf e4 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005e4,%edi
  400535:   e8 d6 fe ff ff          callq  400410 <puts@plt>
/home/stdcall/temp/test.c:4
}
  40053a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40053b:   c3                      retq   
  40053c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

Answer (score 0):

try compile with gcc hello.c -g -o hello

options . then do ojbdump -S hello | less